# Regex \G Search Is Not Working

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a string that looks like:

```
Dim strTestString = "\nOwner: John Smith\n123 Main St\n"
```

I parse out the name without any problems like so:

```
Dim mc As Match = Regex.Match(strTestString, "(?<=\\nOwner: )(.*?)(?=\\n)")
Console.WriteLine(mc.Value.ToString())
```

My problem is when I try to get the Address (123 Main St). I am trying to use the \G metacharacter. I return an empty string when I use the following:

```
mc = Regex.Match(strTestString, "\G(.*?)(?=\\n)")
Console.WriteLine(mc.Value.ToString())
```

The address will NOT always be after the second "\n" - but will always occur after "Owner:".

Any ideas on how to extract the address?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `\G` will only work with `Regex.Matches`. Why not split the string with `\n` / `vbLf`? How do you define the starting and ending boundary of the address?

Comment: Does the string include the `\n` characters ( `\\`` and `n`), or are those newlines? I ask, because that's not how VB.Net encodes newlines.

Answer (score 1):

`\G` matches the start of the string or the position after the last successful match when you search several occurrences.

Your approach doesn't work for three reasons:

- `Regex.Match` only searches one occurrence. You have to use `Regex.Matches` to obtain several results if any.
- If you change the pattern, the search restarts from the beginning of the string. That's why you obtain "Owner:" since `\G` matches the start of the string.
- Whatever, since your pattern doesn't *eat* the newline character after `Smith` *(it's only a test, a lookahead that doesn't consume characters)*, the dot will fail at the position of this newline character.

---

Possible workaround:

Use the `Regex.Match` method with a pattern that describes the two lines and extract the capture groups:

```
(?m)^Owner:(?<owner>.*?)\r?\n(?<addr>.*?)$
```